# What to do with a wallet stuck in "Creating..." state in Mist?

Tags: mist, wallets

On a Windows Ethereum Wallet client I tried to create a new wallet contract. I used default values for fee. The contract got stuck in "creating" state:

[image: Wallet creation process stuck in Mist part 1]

I cannot click on it, it survives Ethereum Wallet application restart.

I tried to create another wallet contract and it succeeded:

[image: Wallet creation process stuck in Mist part 2]

What could be the reason for first contract still having "creating..." status?

What can I do about it now? For example how to get rid of the wallet?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here, but I think you are probably trying to create your own private chain?

This is a common problem in that case. When you do anything in a private chain you must have the node working as a mining node otherwise you will not be able to execute the transaction - it makes sense right?

Quit Mist and go to the Terminal and start your private chain in mining mode. Then start mist and do your task over again.